# Sidon Sets and Diophantine Equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics

Suppose $X$ is a subset of $\{1, \cdots, n\}$ such that the equation $ax_i+bx_j=cx_k+dx_{\ell}$ where $a+b=c+d,$ $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_i, x_j, x_k, x_{\ell} \in X,$ has only trivial solution. A solution is trivial if $x_i=x_j=x_{k}=x_{\ell}.$

What can we say about the size of $X?$ Is this possible that $|X|\geq n^{1-o(1)}$?

I think the answer is related to Sidon Sets, but I could not find any references. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are $a,b,c,d$ fixed? Else there are solutions like $a=c,b=d$, $x_i=x_k$, $x_j=x_l$.

Comment: also maybe you need the reverse inequality for $|X|$?

Comment: Then "is it true" must be read as "is it possible"? And what is $\epsilon$?

Comment: what does it mean "$\epsilon$ is a positive constant depends on $n$?"

Comment: in any case: you may construct the set by adding the elements one by one, this allows to get about $c\cdot n^{1/3}$ elements for free. Is it enough?

Comment: I think the current version might be more clear

Comment: If $a,b,c,d$ are fixed, then saying that they are less than $O(n^{1/4})$ doesn't make sense, since $|X|\ge n^{1-o(1)}$ refers to a limit as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 6):

Such $X$ do indeed exist, and are explicitly constructed in I.Z. Ruzsa, Solving a linear equation in a set of integers, Acta Arith., LXV.3 (1993), pp. 259-282, Theorem 7.5. The whole paper is devoted to upper and lower bounds on sizes of solution-free sets to equations such as the one you are asking about. A mathscinet forward search from that paper should yield further results.

Comment: specifically Theorem 7.5 in this paper seems to the answer original question

Comment: Thank you, Fedor! I knew that the answer was in there, but did not have time this morning to find the exact place. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Kim: you can just ask a separate question here on MO. I am unlikely to be of much help. It has been 13 years since I read that paper - I was a 2nd year undergraduate.